# Force image style to overwrite existing css?

Tags: css

how can I force an image to be aligned hard to the left, regardless of what css applies to the container it is placed in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply a more specific CSS rule to that particular image, e.g. one that references the image by Id or use [!important](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#important-rules).

```
#idOfMyImage { /* Desired CSS here */ }
```

Here's a good (and humorous) overview of specificity in CSS

http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/images/specificitywars-05v2.jpg

Answer (score 3):

You could use `!important` on the style to increase it's precedence over other styles.

```
style="text-align: left !important;"
```

Or

```
#foo { text-align: left !important; }
```

However, this is considered bad practice. Ideally you should give your selectors the level of specificity required. Could you post up your CSS.

Comment: `!important` in the style attribute has no real effect since anything in the style attribute will already override w/e style may be associated with it. Within CSS it can be used, but I would advice sparingly. Tracking down which elements are affected due to the use of an `!important` tag can be bothersome when you need to change it.

Comment: Good point about using the flag on inline styles. You can tell I don't use it often ;)